# Quero que ao dar enter envie um formulario

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, eu tenho um javascript que ao clicar no botão "Pesquisar", vai fazer uma requisição via ajax e pesquisar determinado valor que está no input.

O que preciso é, quando a pessoa escrever no input e der enter, automaticamente clique no button.

```
<input type="text" id="dado" name="dado" placeholder="Descrição" required/>
<button onclick="enviar('0');">Pesquisar</button>
```

Não esta dentro de um formulário, eu tenho que colocar dentro e dar algum type pro button?

Foi o que tentei, mas como é javascript que importa no botão pelo evento onclick, então não chamou a função, o que fazer?

Tenho vários botões na tela para outros javascripts de ajax, e outros inputs, então eu teria que dar id a cada formulário, caso seja algo relacionado, teria um exemplo para dois forms de como fazer ?

Comment: O mais fácil seria você montar o elemento form completo, definir o botão como submit e tratar o evento submit deste formulário. A grande maioria dos navegadores já tentam submeter o formulário ao pressionar enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abaixo segue uma forma de fazer isso através do javascript, inseri um id no button para forçar o evento de clique no mesmo:

```js
document.getElementById("dado")
    .addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        document.getElementById("button-dado").click();
    }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="dado" name="dado" placeholder="Descrição" required/>
<button id="button-dado" onclick="enviar('0');">Pesquisar</button>
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou!

Comment: Magnífico! Eu não ia conseguir (:

Comment: Que bom que resolveu seu problema.